# Combination Problem: Girls picking flowers

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Two girls have picked 10 roses, 15 sunflowers and 15 daffodils. What is the number of ways they can divide the flowers amongst themselves ?

```
(a) 1638
(b) 2100
(c) 2640
(d) None of the above
```

My approach:

By applying `Stars and Bars` where bins can be empty, I'm getting
=$\binom{10+2-1}{1}\times\binom{15+2-1}{1}\times\binom{15+2-1}{1}=2816$

Which is not in the option, what I have assumed wrong

Comment: Any restrictions on what sort of flowers each girls can have?

Comment: What about option $d)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of roses, girl $1$ gets, has $11$ possibilities, for the other flowers we 
 have $16$ possibilities. So, there are $11\times 16\times 16=2816$ ways to divide the
 flowers.

So, option $d)$ is correct.

Comment: The girls are distinct. Your solution does not count cases where girl 1 does not have any flowers of a particular kind. Answer would be 11*16*16

Comment: Oops, you are right. I edited my answer.